# throws Nullpointer Exception

Tags: android, textview

```
TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
String text = "<fontcolor=#cc0029>Erste Farbe</font><font color=#ffcc00>zweiteFare</font>";
yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Getting NPE, I even added internet permission.

Comment: pls accept the answer if you got the desired result.

Comment: all given answer is perfect so you need to accept answer. But my question is that why your code not getting error at compile time. And your question is not related to internet permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change below code line

```
t.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

instead of

```
yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Answer (score 2):

use **t** instead of **yourtextview**

```
TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
String text = "<fontcolor=#cc0029>Erste Farbe</font><font color=#ffcc00>zweiteFare</font>";
t.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the text in the textview and not in the id of the textview.

try to do with this

```
t.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call TextView t instead of calling TextView ID.

Use this `t.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));`
 instead of using 
`yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));`